# Directory changes when importing file in R

Tags: r, import, directory, r-markdown, importerror

In RMarkdown, I've set my root directory and console working directory but I can't get `read.pnm` to import from the correct directory. This is what I have:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = "C:/Users/customdir/.../folder")

library(pixmap)
```

```
getwd()
img = read.pnm("~/folder2/img.pgm")
```

From the output of `getwd()`, I can tell it's in the right directory but I get the error:

```
Warning in file(file, open = "rb") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/user/Documents/folder2/img.pgm': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, open = "rb") : cannot open the connection
```

I don't know why it's looking in `"C:/Users/user/Documents/"` since that's not the directory I specified.

Is there any other directory I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "~" part of the file name points to your personal home directory (not your current working directory). When you use a "~" you are giving an absolute path, not a path relative to your working directory. If you want to find the file in your current working directory, use

```
img = read.pnm("folder2/img.pgm")
```

Comment: Thank you. The reason I added ~ was because just doing "folder2/img.pgm" did not work. But now I notice that I was doing "/folder2/img.pgm" not "folder2/img.pgm", which was causing an error.  Thanks.